# Extract all fields from array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json file named `collection.json`such as :

```
{
    "info" : {
        ...
    },
    "item" : [
        {...}, # A
        {...}, # B
        {...}  # C
    ]

}
```

I want all the fields from the array `item`, like below:

```
{...}, # A
{...}, # B
{...}  # C
```

---

#### What I have tried:

> jq -r '.item' collection.json

With this, I still avec the squares brackets, at the beginning and the end.

> jq -r '.item[]' collection.json

With this, the comma between the fields is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your expected output is neither valid JSON (which would be your first suggestion `jq -r '.item' collection.json` that includes commas AND the array brackets) nor the plain raw content of the elements (which would be your second suggestion `jq -r '.item[]' collection.json` that removes all the surrounding JSON syntax), you will have to build the desired syntax yourself which may depend on what the `.item` array elements actually are.

For instance, convert them into strings using `tostring` and glue them together with the `join` builtin:

```
jq -r '.item | map(tostring) | join(",\n")' collection.json
```